# Inputstream not reading size specified in buffer value

Tags: android

For downloading a content, i am writing file to output stream. I have given the buffer size for byte array as 1024*100, where I expect input stream will read 100kb of data and write to the output stream. But by input stream seems to read on his own. E.g it read 1795 bytes of data first then 3843 and so on. Is it possible to force input stream to read specified amount of bytes each time.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024x100];
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1024x100)) >= 0) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    totalRead += bytesRead;
}
```

Comment: no, your code is just fine - this is how `InputStream#read()` is supposed to work

Comment: Then what is the purpose of len attribute? Can i not force input stream to read say my desired bytes of data at each go

Comment: because it tells the maximum number of bytes that can be read - `"len int: the maximum number of bytes to read.`" - if you dont like it simply use `InputStream#read(byte[] b)`

Comment: so there is no way to ensure that input stream reads the specified amount of bytes?

Comment: or say i want to increase it from 1024 to say 4096 bytes at each go. Can i not force it to happen?

Comment: no - of course you can create a helper method, for example `readFully` or something like that

Comment: Readfully will be like reading all of the data together and writing at one go. It will be more memory consuming i believe

Comment: for example see how `DataInputStream` implements this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/ojluni/src/main/java/java/io/DataInputStream.java#171

Comment: ReadFully will be more memory consuming. So dont think it will be an ideal solution

Comment: so do you want to read entire buffer or not? i dont understand what you want to achieve actually...

Comment: `inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1024x100))` If you want to continue with this than better `inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length))`. It is no good to have twice `1024*100` in your code.

Comment: `Then what is the purpose of len attribute?` Comes in very handy if you want to read for instance 100 bytes in a buffer starting at a certain position.`inputStream.read(buffer, pos, 100)`.

Comment: Thnx @greenapps for your comments. So suppose i want to read say 50 kb at each while loop, what should be my code?

Comment: Hi @pskink Suppose my file is around 5 MB, i want to read say 50 KB at each go of while loop

Comment: so make a buffer of 50k and call `readFully`?

Comment: I want my inputstream to read fixed size of byte till it completes downloading 5 mb of file. For me say it is 50 kb each time

Comment: Any code will be extremely helpful

Comment: i posted the code already - just read it

Comment: Also how can i write that 50kb fully each time till i reach 5 mb

Comment: It makes no sense what you ask. And it is not possible to force `read()` to behave differently. Please tell why you would fill up memory for that? Everybody tries to minimize memory use.

Comment: There is nothing wrong as u mentioned and i agree. Actually over wifi the download is happening just fine, but while on 3G after some bytes has got downloaded, i am getting SocketTimedOut exception. So i want to increase the downloading of bytes at each go of while loop. For that reason i have given 32kb as buffer size and i was expecting that each time, 32 kb will be read till my download is complete. But it seems the read value of bytes is not reading 32 kbs of bytes. It is reading of its own